# TPR & FPR Curve for different classifiers - kNN, NaiveBayes, Decision Trees in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, roc

I'm trying to understand and plot TPR/FPR for different types of classifiers. I'm using kNN, NaiveBayes and Decision Trees in R. With kNN I'm doing the following:

```
clnum <- as.vector(diabetes.trainingLabels[,1], mode = "numeric")
dpknn <- knn(train = diabetes.training, test = diabetes.testing, cl = clnum, k=11, prob = TRUE)
prob <- attr(dpknn, "prob")
tstnum <- as.vector(diabetes.testingLabels[,1], mode = "numeric")
pred_knn <- prediction(prob, tstnum)
pred_knn <- performance(pred_knn, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(pred_knn, avg= "threshold", colorize=TRUE, lwd=3, main="ROC curve for Knn=11")
```

where `diabetes.trainingLabels[,1]` is a vector of labels (class) I want to predict, `diabetes.training` is the training data and `diabetes.testing` is the testing data.

Plot looks like the following:
[image]

The values stored in prob attribute is a numeric vector (decimal between 0 and 1). I convert the class labels factor into numbers and then I can use it with prediction/performance function from ROCR library. Not 100% sure I'm doing it correct but at least it works.

For the NaiveBayes and Decision Trees tho, with prob/raw parameter specified in predict function I don't get a single numeric vector but a vector of lists or matrix where probability for each class is specified (I guess), eg:

```
diabetes.model <- naiveBayes(class ~ ., data = diabetesTrainset)
diabetes.predicted <- predict(diabetes.model, diabetesTestset, type="raw")
```

and `diabetes.predicted` is:

```
tested_negative tested_positive
[1,]    5.787252e-03       0.9942127
[2,]    8.433584e-01       0.1566416
[3,]    7.880800e-09       1.0000000
[4,]    7.568920e-01       0.2431080
[5,]    4.663958e-01       0.5336042
```

The question is how to use it to plot ROC curve and why in kNN I get one vector and for other classifiers I get them separate for both classes?

Answer (score 0):

#### ROC curve

The ROC curve you provided for `knn11` classifier looks off - it is below the diagonal indicating that your classifier assigns class labels correctly *less* than 50% of the time. Most likely what happened there is that you provided wrong class labels or wrong probabilities. If in training you used class labels of 0 and 1 - those same class labels should be passed to ROC curve in the same order (without 0 and one flipping).

Another less likely possibility is that you have a very weird dataset.

#### Probabilities for other classifiers

ROC curve was developed to call events from the radar. Technically it is closely related to predicting an event - probability that you correctly guess the even of a plane approaching from the radar. So it uses one probability. This can be confusing when someone does classification on two classes where "hit" probabilities are not evident, like in your case where you have cases and controls.

However any two class classification can be termed in terms of "hits" and "misses" - you just have to select a class which you will call an "event". In your case having diabetes might be called an event.

So from this table:

> ```
>  tested_negative tested_positive
>  [1,]    5.787252e-03       0.9942127
>  [2,]    8.433584e-01       0.1566416
>  [3,]    7.880800e-09       1.0000000
>  [4,]    7.568920e-01       0.2431080
>  [5,]    4.663958e-01       0.5336042
> ```

You would only have to select one probability - that of an event - probably "tested_positive". Another one "tested_negative" is just `1-tested_positive` because when classifier things that a particular person has diabetes with 79% chance - he at the same time "thinks" that there is a 21% chance of that person not having diabetes. But you only need one number to express this idea, so knn only returns one, while other classifier can return two.

I don't know which library you used for decision trees so cannot help with the output of that classifier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing something fundamentally wrong. [image]

Ideally KNN graph looks like the one above. Here are a few points you can use.

1. Calculate distance in you code.
2. Use below code for prediction in python

## Predicted class

```
print(model_name.predict(test))
```

## 3 nearest neighbors

```
print(model_name.kneighbors(test)[1])
```